# I don't know how to do something with a number (see inside)

Tags: uibutton, uilabel

I have in my app a label and a button.

The label has the number 20.

every I click the button the number decreases in 1.

I set the stating number (20) on view did load.

the problem is that when i leave the app it sets it back to 20.

and i want to return to the number I left the app at.

what to do ? where to set the starting number?

I am using Xcode and objective c.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to save the number:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:number forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then when you need to set number for label:

```
number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"key"];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
```

Comment: can I gat your email maybe ? and send you the project ?

Comment: nsobsession@gmail.com